# How many integers between $10000$ and $99999$, inclusive, are divisible by $3$ or $5$ or $7?$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How many integers between $10000$ and $99999$, inclusive, are divisible by $3$ or $5$ or $7$?

How would I tackle these types of problems?

Comment: how have  you tried??

Comment: Your efforts please..

Comment: for example for 5 ...see that 10000 is divisible by five and every groups of five starting from it contains a number divisible by 5....number of such groups are ..

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the use of this problem?

Comment: @0.5772156649... Do you know about Project Euler?

Comment: I know what it is...just didn't put the two together

Comment: try using the inclusion-exclusion principle for three sets.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Let $I=[10000,99999]$ and:
$$ A = \{n\in I:n\equiv 0\pmod{3}\},$$
$$ B = \{n\in I:n\equiv 0\pmod{5}\},$$
$$ C = \{n\in I:n\equiv 0\pmod{7}\}.$$
Compute $|A|,|B|,|C|,|A\cap B|,|A\cap C|,|B\cap C|,|A\cap B\cap C|$, then recall that:
$$ |A\cup B \cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|.$$
You will get something that is pretty close to $\left|I\,\right|-\left|I\,\right|\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)=\frac{19}{35}|I|.$

Comment: what's the intuition behind that estimation?

Comment: @Soke: $|A|$ is about $|I|/3$ and so on, so by expanding the last product you get a number that is almost the same as before.

Comment: Yup ok, that makes sense. Though wouldn't it be $|I| - $ that expression? (The signs seem flipped right now)

Comment: @Soke: you're right, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I'm willing to do a lot to avoid inclusion-exclusion, so:

$3\cdot 5\cdot 7=105$, so the pattern of multiples repeat every 105 numbers. Since you have $90000=857\cdot 105+15$ you can get the answer by taking 857 times the number of divisors in a 105-number period, plus those-among $10000, 10001, \cdots, 10014$ that are multiples of 3/5/7, which you can count by hand.

How many multiples are there in an 105-period? The *non-multiples* are exactly the numbers that are *coprime to* 105, and the number of those has a fancy name, *Euler's totient function*, $\varphi(105)$.

Since we know the prime factorization of $105$ (which we made just before by multiplying together some primes) it is easy to see what $\varphi(105)$ is, namely $(3-1)\cdot(5-1)\cdot(7-1)=2\cdot 4\cdot 6 = 48$. (If we don't already know this is the number of residue classes coprime to $105$ it also follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Thus the number of *multiples* of {3,5,7} is then $105-48=57$ so the number we're looking for is
$$ 57\cdot 857 + \text{number of multiple from }10000\text{ to }10014 $$